# Almost all knots are non invertible

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

K. Murasugi mentions in p.45 of his book "Knot Theory and Its Aplications" that almost all knots are non invertible, meaning that they are not equivallent to their reverses, where the reverse of an oriented knot is the same knot but with the other orientation. However he does not reference any source for this statement, and I couldn't find anything on the matter, so I would like to know if there is a proof of this and where to find it, as I understand that proving a knot is not invertible is no easy task.

Comment: There are several references given at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_knot).

Comment: Most likely, he simple means the experimental evidence obtained by looking at knots with "small" (at most 16) crossings.

Comment: Makes sense, references in wikipedia are empiric. At first I thought he would mean something like the Erdös-Wilson Theorem in graph theory where you do have an actual limit over the number of vertices of the number of graphs of certain family divided by the total number of graphs with that amount of vertices, the limit being 1 which definitely makes it clearer to state that there are "more" graphs of that type than outside of it. Thank you both.